# "X ... one ..." vs "the X ... one ..."

Tags: syntactic-analysis

What's the right construction?

Example:

> I spent the whole night listening **to silence**, one as deep as the
>   bottom of the sea.
>
> I spent the whole night listening **to the silence**, one as deep as the
>   bottom of the sea.

Or maybe both are right, and they just refer to a different kind of silence? I'm a bit skeptic about the second case. I think the "the" and "one" are imcompatible in situations like this?

Comment: The two have slightly different meanings, but in fact the second one seems "better" (more likely) to me.

Comment: It may be a personal preference. For my own standards of clarity, the first sentence would have to say "a silence", which doesn't really ring very nicely. I suspect that the first one is also fine for someone who isn't quite so peculiarly anal.

Comment: *Hello silence my old friend, I've come to talk to you again...* The original line has "darkness" but it's just showing how "silence", (personified) without the article, can be used to great effect.

Comment: I revised my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first version doesn't work, because it treats *silence* as uncountable ("silence" as opposed to "a silence"), and *one* requires a countable antecedent.

The second version does not have this problem (since "the silence" can be countable). However, the use of *the* mostly only works if the silence has already been mentioned, or if it's already obvious that there is silence. If that is the case, then — perfect. Otherwise, you may have to go for a third option:

> I spent the whole night listening to a silence as deep as the bottom of the sea.

(Incidentally, this is probably subjective, but I find the phrasing "as deep as the bottom of the sea" to be a bit awkward. I'd suggest "as deep as the sea" instead.)

Comment: I think all three, *silence*, *a silence*, and *the silence* are all possible and acceptable - but with very finely nuanced shades of meaning. But I do agree with your point that using *deep* and *bottom* is duplicatory.

Comment: -1: The first version _does_ work. Never heard "silence is golden"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Sure I've heard it. Now, if only it were relevant in some way . . .

Comment: @ruakh: Okay I'll spell it out: it demonstrates that "silence" may be used in its uncountable sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Obviously; but no one suggested that it *couldn't*, so -- not relevant. All I said is that the pronoun *one* requires a countable antecedent. Since "Silence is golden" doesn't use that pronoun . . . well, you're a smart person, you'll figure it out.

Comment: I think I'll just leave you to calm down. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Don't worry, I'm actually quite calm. If you still have a point to make, make it. :-)

Answer (score 7):

In the first sentence, silence is general (silence that is silence, wherever and whenever) and then restricted to be the specific one that's as deep as the bottom of the sea. The awkward point, as ruakh has mentioned before me, is that the pronoun "one" is referring to an uncountable noun (silence). In some cases this might be more tolerable with the help of the context:

> -Do you want black coffee or white coffee? (uncountable coffee)
>   -A black one please. (countable; a cup of coffee)

But in your sentence it still is a little awkward. So I, too, prefer *silence* to be countable. Furthermore, I'd replace *deep* (having a large distance to the bottom from the surface) with *profound* (far below the surface):

- *I spent the whole night listening to a silence, one as profound as the bottom of the sea.*

In the second sentence, we have "the silence" (a particular one) followed by an identifying expression: "*one as* ...".
The definite article "the" prompts us to look for qualifying information. Since no prior mention has been made of silence, this information should be deduced either from the context (the silence that I was immersed in at that moment), or from the following expression. But the following does not have one of those common structures to qualify a previous word (e.g. the silence *that* ..., the The Silence *of* the Lambs, etc), and if the context is to be sufficient to qualify *silence*, there won't remain a connection between *silence* and the following expression. This is probably why you feel funny about the second sentence.

On the other hand, omitting the verb *to be*, while not as common in modern usage, is (was) acceptable when the meaning is (was) clear:

> Who so firm that cannot be seduced?

So you can interpret the second one as

- *I spent the whole night listening to the silence, one (that was) as profound as the bottom of the sea.*

My hunch is that neither is wrong, but the first (as modified here or in ruakh's post) is more natural.